# get multiple user data in a single query

Tags: asana

I did the following.

```
curl -u $API_KEY https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users
```

then I collect the IDs of all users.

Is there a way to get all users info in a single query. I want some think like

```
curl -u $API_KEY https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/2423237500000 & 7124173919380
```

instead of two separate query

```
curl -u $API_KEY https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/2423237500000
curl -u $API_KEY https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/7124173919380
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work at Asana.)

When you retrieve the list of users you can fetch more than just their ID and name. Use the `opt_fields` parameter for specific individual fields, or if you really need the whole record than use `opt_expand`, as described in the docs here:

https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options

Comment: Thanks for respond. I did the following and it works as I expected.
curl -u $API_KEY https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users?opt_fields=name,email

I guess I can do the same for tasks and projects? 
Thank you,